# Does Webkit support SOCKS proxy?

Tags: webkit, socks

Does Webkit support SOCKS proxy? I have searched for it and I did not find any reference of SOCKS proxy in webkit.
I am looking for a C++ cross-platform webBrowser API for Linux and iOS which support SOCKS proxy (SOCKS5). Any suggestions?